# How to use underscore.js to assign an object to $rootscope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, underscore.js

I have this variable holding the data

```js
var tooltipsJson = [{
    "Language": "en-GB",
    "Section": "Sales&Marketing",
    "ItemName": "CalculationType",
    "Texts": "Having selected the account heading select the calculation ..."
  },
  {
    "Language": "en-GB",
    "Section": "Taxes",
    "ItemName": "Save",
    "Texts": "The Master Tax Table has been pre populated with the current UK, ..."
  }
];
```

and I want to use the underscore.js **each**

```
_.each(.........)
```

so that when I put:

```
console.log({{tooltipsJson.Taxes.Save}});
```

to display the text

> The Master Tax Table has been pre populated with the current UK, ...

I want the Texts attribute to be assigned to a local variable

Comment: $rootscope, is this angularjs or angular 2+?

Comment: I am using the angularjs

Comment: Please explain better the problem. Where did you find tooltipsJson.Taxes.Save? I can't see such function.

Comment: I want the attribute text to be assign to a local variable

Comment: There's no such thing as a "json object". What you have there is an array of objects. That's it. Also, why do you need to use underscore? Plain old JavaScript can do this just as easily...

Comment: Mike he "needs" to use Underscore. I told him about ES6 in a post in Facebook already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try;

```
$scope.obj = {};

_.each(tooltipsJson, function( val, key ) {
    $scope.obj[key] = val;
});
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work and you can see it here

https://jsfiddle.net/Chrisly27/sbv1o75f/8/

Comment: You did not use Angular in your exam. You must add angular lib.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all "Texts" attribute of the objects in the array you call .each() like this:

```
_.each(tooltipsJson, function(item){
    console.log(item.Texts);
});
```

Comment: I want to assign the Text attribute to local variable, please... I tried that but it is not exactly what I want